# Visitor pattern for tree mutation and shared pointer problem

Tags: c++, c++20, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to implement visitor pattern for n-ary tree mutation. Currently i'm stuck with shared pointers. Mutator operates on each tree node and can return either pointer to a node itself w/o any changes, or a pointer to a copy of modified node (original node cannot be modified directly). But obviously i can't build a shared pointer from a raw pointer inside `Visit` method, neither i can't make a shared pointer from `this` inside a `Mutate` method. The only idea that comes into my mind, is to create another class which will be holding pointer and pass this class pointer to visitor instead, but perhaps there is a better solution?

```cpp
// Forward declarations
class ExpressionTreeMutator;

struct BaseExpr;

enum class ExpressionType {
  kString,
  kInt,
};

using ExprPtr = std::shared_ptr<BaseExpr>;

struct BaseExpr {
  explicit BaseExpr(ExpressionType expression_type) : expression_type_(expression_type) {}

  virtual ~BaseExpr() = default;

  virtual ExprPtr Mutate(ExpressionTreeMutator* visitor) const = 0;

  ExpressionType expression_type_;
};

// Curiously recurring template pattern
template<typename T>
struct Expr : public BaseExpr {
  explicit Expr(ExpressionType expression_type) : BaseExpr(expression_type) {}

  ~Expr() override = default;

  ExprPtr Mutate(ExpressionTreeMutator* visitor) const override;
};

struct String : public Expr<String> {
  explicit String(std::string value) : Expr(ExpressionType::kString),
                                       value_(std::move(value)) {}

  std::string value_;
};

struct Int : public Expr<Int> {
  explicit Int(int64_t value) : Expr(ExpressionType::kInt),
                                value_(value) {}

  int64_t value_;
};

class ExpressionTreeMutator {
public:
  virtual ~ExpressionTreeMutator() = default;

protected:
  template<typename T>
  friend
  struct Expr;

  virtual ExprPtr Visit(Int const* expr) {
//    return expr ??? (in some cases return ptr as it is)
  };

  virtual ExprPtr Visit(String const* expr) {
//     return String::Make(expr) ??? (make a copy)
  };
};

template<typename T>
ExprPtr Expr<T>::Mutate(ExpressionTreeMutator* visitor) const {
  return visitor->Visit(dynamic_cast<T const*>(this));
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use references instead of shared pointer in the visit method?

Comment: Lots of solutions.  Easiest and worst is shared from this.  I like replacing shared ptrs with copy on write based immutable pointers.  This requires structural changes to algorithms you'll find awkward however.

Comment: You are not using that T in Expr.

Comment: @jlanik it is used for Mutate method, for proper dispatching, look at the last lines of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is tagged C++20, I'd suggest to use std::variant and std::visit instead.

Otherwise, you can inherit from std::enable_shared_from_this, which allows to create shared_ptr from within methods of X.

You can also use mutate not to do the actual mutation, but to return appropriate function object that does the mutation and then pass the shared_ptr to this object.

Comment: it is tagged `visitor` not `visit`

Comment: sorry I meant it is tagged c++20